# Can't get ath10k (Killer Wifi 1535) to work on Freya

Tags: release-freya, wifi, drivers, networking

i've installed Freya and everything is working nicely out of the box, except the WiFi.

My laptop has a Killer 1535, so i followed their instructions (http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/20-killer-wireless-ac-in-linux-ubuntu-debian) and placed the content of kvalo's QCA6174 on my /lib/firmware/ath10k. My /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0 content is:

> board-2.bin
>
> board.bin
>
> firmware-4.bin

Since Freya uses a 3.x kernel i had to install the ath10k driver through backports.
So i installed the linux-headers and the build-essential, downloaded backports and ran these commands:

> make defconfig-ath10k
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

Everything went fine and the install told me to reboot.
After the reboot the wireless icon appeared and listed my networks, but i couldn't establish a connection to them. After a few seconds they were not displayed anymore.

Then i've ran

> dmesg | grep "ath"

Here's what i've got:

```
[    1.227654] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: ebbc4f7d1a69d375881e66dfa532d0f61eac585e'
[    3.309690] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.310606] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.496935] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.497129] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-pci-168c:003e:1a56:1535.bin failed with error -2
[    3.497133] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2
[    3.497301] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    3.497303] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    5.617141] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff, 168c:003e:1a56:1535 fallback) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 htt 3.26 wmi 4 cal otp max_sta 32
[    5.617144] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 1 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    6.615026] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: suspend timed out - target pause event never came
[    9.682192] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    9.682194] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    9.682196] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    9.682196] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   14.909701] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable ani by default: -11
[   17.909306] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   26.207947] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   29.207463] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   37.490244] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable ani by default: -11
[   40.489779] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   48.772370] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   51.771903] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   60.054655] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   63.054276] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   71.336908] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   74.336456] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   82.619270] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   85.618698] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   93.901449] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   96.901045] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  105.183758] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  108.183282] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  116.465947] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  119.465449] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
```

Now I'm kind of lost. Any idea?

Comment: What backports version?

Comment: Hello @Jeremy31, i've ran the most recent version of backports. 
Then i saw one post of yours at the mint or arch forums (not sure of which one was) stating that i should use a specific date version. I also tried with version, but still no luck :(

Comment: I would uninstall the dated version and use the latest stable 4.4.2 backports or install the 4.5 kernel from kernel.org.  The 4.5 kernel will show the crc32 result for the board.bin and firmware file loaded.  I suspect you have an issue with board.bin as that is usually when the -11 error is reported.  It might be worth doing `sudo rm -r /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw3.0` and then redownload from kvallo's github.  With 4.5 kernel you could compare crc32 with https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343/comments/66

Comment: I've tried to upgrade to a 4.x kernel in order to have the driver included but the performance with the new kernel was really bad. I've had lots os graphic glitches. I would also like to keep the stock kernel.

Comment: The 4.4.2 backports also support loading of board-2.bin  With the 20151120 I think some people needed to rename board-2.bin to board.bin

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on a new Skylake Intel NUC (nuc6i3syk, I know it's different but also new hardware): No or only partial wifi on kernels 3.x and ripping graphic glitches on kernels 4.3-4.5 and everything in between.

What does now work for me is kernel 4.2.8.
Both 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz bands now work and no graphic glitches. 
Did you try 4.2.8 as well?

Comment: Made a clean install and installed the 4.2.8 kernel. The GUI doesn't even load. Checked if the wifi was working using the shell and it wasn't. Removing the 4.2.8 kernel....

Comment: Sorry to hear that. As said, it worked for me and the new intel chipsets.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I decided to give it a try because i'm also on a skylake chipset. I get really pissed off when i follow the manufacturer documentation and the stuff doesn't work :(